# Parsing XML file in C# (with using xmlschemas?)

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

How can I parse this XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<V8Exch:_1CV8DtUD xmlns:V8Exch="http://www.1c.ru/V8/1CV8DtUD/" xmlns:core="http://v8.1c.ru/data" xmlns:v8="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <V8Exch:Data>
<v8:CatalogObject.Obj>
      <v8:IsFolder>false</v8:IsFolder>
          <v8:Ref xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Фізичніособи">433da912-9da5-11e5-822a-f079599615ce</v8:Ref>
<v8:DeletionMark>false</v8:DeletionMark>
      <v8:Parent xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Фізичніособи">4541cd82-9cfb-11e5-b79c-f079599615ce</v8:Parent>
      <v8:Code>000000007</v8:Code>
      <v8:Description>FullName</v8:Description>
      <v8:LastNmae>LastNmae</v8:LastNmae>
      <v8:FirstName>FirstName</v8:FirstName>
      <v8:SecondName>SecondName</v8:SecondName>
      <v8:Edu>
        <v8:НомерДиплома> 1234 </v8:НомерДиплома>
        <v8:НазваНавчельногоЗакладу>Iмені Івана Франка</v8:НазваНавчельногоЗакладу>
        <v8:датаВидачіДиплома>1981-06-27T00:00:00</v8:датаВидачіДиплома>
      </v8:Edu>
    </v8:CatalogObject.Obj>
  </V8Exch:Data>
  <PredefinedData/>
</V8Exch:_1CV8DtUD>
```

I'm trying touse this C#

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("CatalogObject"))
                {   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load("C:\\1.xml");
                    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} = {1}", child.Name, child.InnerText));
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("--------------");
                }
```

code, but it isn't work for this file. It just do nothing. What i must to use to parse this file?
Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get? Or what other problems do you encounter?

Comment: You can try using either [XMLReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx) or via [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) do you want me to elaborate about that?

Comment: doc.SelectNodes uses XPath to select nodes, if you do not provide a path it assumes you want root level nodes, but your CatalogObject nodes are child nodes of the Data node. You might want to read a tutorial about XPath, e.g. http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/using-xpath-with-the-xmldocument-class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc.SelectNodes("CatalogObject")
```

won't match, for 2 reasons:

1. The element's name in your XML sample is "CatalogObject.Obj", not
   "CatalogObject".
2. The element is namespaced ("v8").

So the proper expression would be:

```
doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='CatalogObject.Obj']")
```

Comment: BTW, to be 100% accurate, you would have to check for the correct namespace, too: `//*[local-name()='CatalogObject.Obj'][namespace-uri()='http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config']`

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication65
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement _1CV8DtUD = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = _1CV8DtUD.Name.Namespace;
            XNamespace ns_V8 = _1CV8DtUD.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("v8");
            XNamespace ns_xsi = _1CV8DtUD.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi");

            var results = _1CV8DtUD.Descendants(ns_V8 + "CatalogObject.Obj").Select(x => new {
                isFolder = (Boolean)x.Element(ns_V8 + "IsFolder"),
                type = (string)x.Element(ns_V8 + "Ref").Attribute(ns_xsi + "type")
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```